# ExpandableListView child views positioning on group expand or scroll

Tags: android, xamarin.android, expandablelistview

I'm working on implementing an `ExpandableListView` with my custom Adapter that extends `BaseExpandableAdapter` .

Working with the MVP model i successfully inflate all the groups and views in the right way. Piece of my `GetChildView()`

```
public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    BetViewHolder holder = new BetViewHolder(_BetPresenter);
    var view = convertView;

    if (view != null)
        holder = view.Tag as BetViewHolder;
    else
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)_Context
                        .GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        holder = new BetViewHolder(_BetPresenter);
        view = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.live_bet_view_item, null);
        holder.InitEventViews(view);

        view.Tag = holder;
    }

    _BetPresenter.OnBindBetEventView(holder, groupPosition, childPosition);

    return view;
}
```

Inside the presenter at `OnBindBetEventView` i set the data on the corresponding view.

***The problem***

Each child item has a 3 custom components(Buttons) which are selectable. And in general each child view is relatively complex. When i select one of the buttons of the child view it successfully changes the color like it should, but also other child views from other groups change get selected too. The strange part comes when i scroll or collapse/expand a group.

The selected views are changing and some others are getting selected instead. 'Playing' with the groups it messes the all the selected buttons without a specific pattern.

[image]

*Clicking the first button also checks another button on another group. It was not already selected by me. Scrolling and expanding groups changes the order of selected buttons*

***NOTE***

After lots of debugging i realized that every 2 buttons the Unique view id's of the buttons are duplicate. Meaning that the instance of the view is exactly the same. Maybe is due to recycling or something. The point is that i need to preserve the state of my selected views without letting the adapted change the position of my views.

Comment: Hi, from `The problem`, I am not sure what is your problem, could you please post a .gif?  I have tried to reproduce your problem, but the result is correct, only the button which I clicked will change the color, not other button or other group's button. Or can you show more codes for us? Like the `OnBindBetEventView` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recycling mechanism of the `ExpandableList` was causing this strange behavior due to the reuse-ability of the views. The ChildView with the clicked item was recycled once it was out of screen and inflating it again on a different position

*I realize that due to the fact that the views had exactly the same unique hash created by Android. There was a duplication*

**I solved it by checking my model's state everytime the adapter tries to inflate the view, on the position it tries to inflate it.**

Here is the `ViewHolder` method called from the adapter at `GetChildView()`

```
public void SetEventToView(Event eventItem)
{
    txtCompetitor1.Text = eventItem.Competitor1;
    txtCompetitor2.Text = eventItem.Competitor2;
    txtTime.Text = eventItem.Time;
    txtScore.Text = eventItem.Score;

    for (int i = 0; i < _OddButtonList.Count; i++)
    {
        _OddButtonList[i].OddID = eventItem.BetItems[i].ID;
        _OddButtonList[i].SetPriceText(eventItem.BetItems[i].BetOdd);
        _OddButtonList[i].SetOnClickListener(this);
        SetButtonState(eventItem, _OddButtonList[i], i);
    }
}
```